# Images cropped (stretched) when dragging from outlook to .net application

Tags: vb.net, outlook, drag-and-drop

We have an application that users drag files from their desktop or from outlook onto.  This works very well for actual files, for actual emails, and for attachments to emails...  what isn't working is when the user drags image that is imbedded in an email.  We can get the image, but only sort of... it gets saved with the correct dimensions, but the image is too wide (stretched... or the resolution is off or something).

We've tried a ton of google searches, everything we can think of with regard to the object we receive from the `DragEventArgs`.

```
   Private Sub ProcessDroppedAttachmentMeta(e As DragEventArgs, Optional ByVal node As TreeNode = Nothing)
        Dim dataObject As System.Windows.Forms.DataObject = e.Data
        Dim Image As System.Drawing.Image = dataObject.GetImage

        Dim savePath As String = "C:\temp\testfile.bmp" 

        Image.Save(savePath)

    End Sub
```

How do we get this image to save correctly?

Comment: Outlook returns different data types when an Image is droppen. The first is a DataType named "Woozle". You don't want this. You need the DataFormat "Bitmap", which is returned directly as Bitmap object instead of a MemoryStream. This will return you the original Bitmap with the correct dimensions. The Image is also contained in the "Html" DataFormat, which is a complete reproduction of the Email content, in the MS Office XML notation.

Comment: BTW, the "Woozle" DataType is a convertible RTF document, which contains a scaled PNG image. The `IDataObject` `GetData()` method transforms it to a Bitmap object if you ask it to. This is probably what you're getting now. As a note, you set the image type as `"C:\temp\testfile.bmp"`, with the `BMP` type extension, but this: `Image.Save(savePath)`, creates a `PNG` file. The default, if you don't specify an `ImageFormat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Dim html As String = dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Html)
    Dim embeddedImagePaths As New List(Of String)
    Dim txtsearch As New TextParser.ParseTracker(html)
    Dim nextImagePath As String = String.Empty

    Do
        nextImagePath = TextParser.ParseTracker.getText(txtsearch, "<v:imagedata src=""file:///", """")
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nextImagePath) Then embeddedImagePaths.AddUnique(nextImagePath)
    Loop While Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nextImagePath)

    For Each f As String In embeddedImagePaths
        File.Copy(f, "C:\temp\" & IO.Path.GetFileName(f), True)
    Next
```

Comment: This bit of code solved my problem.  An image embedded in an outlook email can now be dragged to my application.  My application saves the image in its full glory for additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar issue, but in a different context. The cause was that the resolution wasn't right for the imported image as it had to deal with the container's resolution. I dealt with it this way:

```
Dim graphics As System.Drawing.Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics 'Get the resolution from the current form
Dim imageClone As New Bitmap(image)
imageClone.SetResolution(graphics.DpiX, graphics.DpiY)
PlaceWhereINeedTheImage.Image = imageClone
```

It's kind of a shot in the dark as these issues are hard to troubleshoot, but it's worth a try. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this did not resolve the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

If an image is 800px wide and your email is 600px wide, Outlook will display the image as 800px wide. Outlook ignores inline style sheets to set the size. The best way to make Outlook display the width you want is something like this:

```
<img src="#" width="580" />
```

Since Outlook ignores the inline style sheet and any css classes attached, you can use those to fine-tune the display of the email in various other email clients. As an example, for mobile:

```
<img src="#" width="580" style="max-width: 100%;" />
```

Outlook will continue to display the image at 580px and if the viewport changes to 425px, it can resize itself so it fits a smaller size.

Good luck.

Comment: This doesn't relate to my question really... thanks for your effort though.